# Unable to set correctly a firewall in mininet with sdn and opeflow ovs (UDP Version )

Tags: udp, firewall, sdn, mininet, openflow

I'm experimenting with mininet in ubuntu 14 in order to create a basic firewall which blocks the udp packets from one host ( **h1= 10.0.0.1** ) to another ( **h4= 10.0.0.4** ).

Those hosts are in the same vlan and in different switchs (if that can be of any help). Also I would like to block it the udp packets which the destination port as **5001**.
[image]

To do it so, i have launch two xterm in h1(in mininet) in order to check the ping is working correctly and also launch the packets to h4. *xterm h1: "iperf -u -c10.0.0.4 -p 5001 -i 5 -b 200K -t 360"*.

In mininet I also have open a xterm h4 to set it up as a server listening in the port 5001. *xterm h4: "iperf -s -u -p 5001 -i 5​"*.

When I guess the rule I have to introduce is this one **"sh ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 udp_dst=5001,nw_proto=17,actions=drop"**

But, it doesnt work due to the packets are still arriving. The ping works fine, but ( and here comes the main problem) the packet arrives at the server and it shouldn't. 
[image]

Any help please?

Thank you very much

Here I leave you the screenshots of the network topology and also what I appear in the xterm windows.

Comment: I tried this new command and also it didnt work too: sh ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 ip,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=10.0.0.4,nw_proto=17,tp_dst=5001,udp_dst=5001,actions=drop

Comment: Can you dump the flows in s1 and s2 before and after you install the rule?

Comment: i am also having similar problem..

Comment: i observed when a flow with high data rate hits a switch and switch does not have that flow rule then this problem occurs

Comment: Did u solved this problem??